# ¿Cómo sé que parámetro me da la función chi2.fit de la librería scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy

Tengo el siguiente código:

```py
Parametros = ss.chi2.fit(COPYDATAENERO2["CONSUMO_ENERO"])
Parametros
```

Y me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
(1.790051323619652, 0.9999999999999998, 2.3050947851807533)
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿esta función que parámetros da (media, desviación estándar, grados de libertad, etc.) y cómo sé cuál es cuál?

Answer (score 1):

Te adjunto la [documentacion oficial (function fit)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit), ella te respondera mejor que nadie a todas tus preguntas.